# How to schedule Notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to schedule notifications in my project. I don't get any errors or runtime crashes, however for some reason I don't get any notifications on the simulator when scheduling. I am not sure where exactly I am going wrong, as I have been successful in doing so in a previous project.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

```
import UserNotifications

func addNotification(title: String, category: String, UI: String, date: Date) {

    // Remove Notification

    removeNotifcation(UI: UI)

    // Create Notification
    // iOS 10 Notification

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        let notif = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        notif.title = title
        notif.subtitle = "Reminder for \(title)"
        notif.body = "Your Reminder for \(title) set for \(date)"
        notif.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        notif.categoryIdentifier = UI

        let today = Date()

        let interval = date.timeIntervalSince(today as Date)

        let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: title, content: notif, trigger: notifTrigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                // completion(Success: false)
            } else {
                //completion(Sucess: true)
            }
        })
    } else {
        let newNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

        newNotification.category = category
        newNotification.userInfo = [ "UUID"  : UI]
        newNotification.alertBody = "Your reminder for \(title)"
        newNotification.fireDate = date
        //notification.repeatInterval = nil
        newNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(newNotification)

    }

}

func removeNotifcation(UI: String) {

    //Remove Notif
    //iOS 10 Notification
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [UI])
    } else {
        //Remove Notif

        let app:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
            let notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
            let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo!
            let uuid = userInfoCurrent["UUID"] as! String
            if uuid == UI {
                //Cancelling local notification
                app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is how I am calling the methods

```
dataManager.addNotification(title: "String", category: "001", UI: uuid, date: datePicker.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notifications don't appear when app is in foreground only if you implement `willPresent` delegate method and because of

```
 let today = Date()
```

this date makes it triggers when you run it , so add a time interval and send app to background and you'll see it  , plus make sure you request a permission for it in `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        print("granted: (\(granted)")
    }

  return true
}
```

Also you can have a look to this [tutorial](http://www.thomashanning.com/push-notifications-local-notifications-tutorial/)

//

**Edit :** to verify it triggers anyway implement this

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

      print("handling notifications with the TestIdentifier Identifier")

     completionHandler()

}
```

and set the delegate to the VC

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Comment: But I do user an interval,  I set the interval using the date passed to the method and setting the interval from today  

       ' let interval = date.timeIntervalSince(today as Date)'

       ' let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false) '

      '  let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: title, content: notif, trigger: notifTrigger) '

Comment: Also I do ask for permissions

Comment: but you didin't add any time offset to the interval , pass this trigger **let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)** , after the app launch send it to background to see the notification before the 5 seconds end